# Создать отдельный процесс, независимый от приложения

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Ткните носом в материал.
Нужно создать процесс, независимый от приложения, который будет выполнять определенные методы приложения в назначенное время (даже если приложение вырубили). Никак не могу понять, как это правильно называется, чтобы нарыть хоть какую-то инфу.

Comment: Во-первых - это называется бекграунд.
Во-вторых, вам лучше это на Андроиде делать.

Comment: Приложение для iOS. По правде говоря, нужно делать бекап телефонной книги, допустим, каждых два дня. С бекапом и тел. книгой проблем нет. Остался бекграунд. Тем более нужен бекграунд, который будет выполнятся, если приложение "убито", а не только висит в бекграунде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это запрещено политикой Apple. Ваше приложение не пропустят в AppStore.

Но если очень надо, то iOS это unix-based система, и вам следует посмотреть в сторону [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) и иже с ним.

Comment: т.е. чтобы сохранять бекап тел.книги, допустим каждые два дня, то нужно чтобы приложение было в бэкграунде, но никак не терминейтед. Я правильно понял?

Comment: "Но если очень надо" - нужно "правильно" :)

Comment: Исходя из того, что вычитал, получается так: Приложение запускается системой в бекграунде в определенное время, приложение должно успеть обработать данные в течение 30 секунд, и потом система его затерминейтид. В принцыпе такой вариант подходит. На 500 акков тел. книги уходит примерно 1-2 сек.

Comment: Бэк апп телефонной книги делается айклаудом. Во-вторых, чтобы вам дали 30 секунд после сворачивания приложения, вам нужно это приложение открыть. Можете запланировать пуш уведомления на каждые 2 часа, пользователь если их свайпнет, откроет Ваше приложение, тут вы и мутите бек ап. Так же есть хаки, по отсрочки таймаута в 30 секунд, но это надо гуглить.

Comment: про айклауд я вкурсе, НО, всегда есть заказчик, который хочет пользоваться не просто айклаудом.